# How to create a fixed number of turtles at a certain point?

Tags: netlogo

This may seem like a very simple question to ask but at present I do not know how to create a controllable number of turtles. In addition to this I do not know how to set the coordinates where the turtles should spawn. Ideally I would like the turtles to spawn on a patch that the user will draw out in the U.I. so that the turtles can then move along the network the user will have drawn in the U.I. Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patches use the sprout command

```
Ask patches [
                      Sprout 5 [set color red ]
                      ]
```

Asks all the patches to make 5 red turtles.

Netlogo has fantastic documentation 
The netlogo dictionary in help is insanely useful.

Or just ask one

```
Ask patch 4 5 [sprout 1]
```

Comment: would it be possible for me to make a patch spawn turtles based on its colour not on its coordinates?

Comment: Like  ask patches with[pcolor = red][hatch 5 []] ?

Comment: yes that's great thanks. now how would I set the speed of these turtles I have created?

Comment: That is different question and is context specific. Make a new question and show the code you use to move your cars.

Answer (score 1):

`create-turtles` takes in the number of turtles to create. It also allows you to pass in a block of code that will then be run by the created turtles. So you can do:

```
create-turtles 50 [
  setxy 3.5 4.7
]
```

This will create 50 turtles at the coordinates `(3.5, 4.7)`.